# How to generate easy to read colorful output for iterm 2

Tags: colors, iterm2

I've some tests based on Webdriver which I'm running on a node on my local. I'm using iterm 2, and although I'm using solarized theme which works great for Git but apparently it doesn't help a lot with the Java console output. Here's my console output looks:

[image]

Is there a theme that I can use to make it more easy on the eyes.

Comment: If the application is not outputting color escape-sequences then it does not matter which iTerm theme is set to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

Comment: On that thought, Can I manipulate the output directly in eclipse's console? If that's a possibility then I can probably try to look at results in eclipse console window rather than using iterm2.